# How do i achieve this kind of sorting with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So i have a 'structure' like below & i need to sort it with the order of the 'key values' below for getting the "output" below. how can i achieve this?

**STRUCTURE:**

```
[
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "100",
            1 YEAR: "200",
            3 MONTHS: "30",
            6 MONTHS: "400"}

    },
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "500",
            1 YEAR: "40",
            3 MONTHS: "700",
            6 MONTHS: "800"}

    },
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "199",
            1 YEAR: "1989",
            3 MONTHS: "597",
            6 MONTHS: "20"}

    },
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "356",
            1 YEAR: "10",
            3 MONTHS: "877",
            6 MONTHS: "1145"}

    }
]
```

**KEY VALUES:**

```
["10", "20", "30", "40"]
```

**OUTPUT AFTER SORTING**

```
[
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "356",
            1 YEAR: "10",
            3 MONTHS: "877",
            6 MONTHS: "1145"}

    },
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "199",
            1 YEAR: "1989",
            3 MONTHS: "597",
            6 MONTHS: "20"}

    },
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "100",
            1 YEAR: "200",
            3 MONTHS: "30",
            6 MONTHS: "400"}

    },
    {
        rs: {
            1 MONTHS: "500",
            1 YEAR: "40",
            3 MONTHS: "700",
            6 MONTHS: "800"}

    }
]
```

I want to filter the data structure format i am receiving from an API endpoint to sort it according to the values so that it is in the same order as the key array generated.

Comment: Please let me know in what way my post is not abiding by the high standards set by this forum so that i can learn and improve on it next time onward. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for the wanted order and get the value of the object which match for sorting.

```js
const
    getValue = o => Object.values(o).find(v => values.includes(v)),
    data = [{ rs: { "1 MONTHS": "100", "1 YEAR": "200", "3 MONTHS": "30", "6 MONTHS": "400" } }, { rs: { "1 MONTHS": "500", "1 YEAR": "40", "3 MONTHS": "700", "6 MONTHS": "800" } }, { rs: { "1 MONTHS": "199", "1 YEAR": "1989", "3 MONTHS": "597",  "6 MONTHS": "20" } }, { rs: { "1 MONTHS": "356", "1 YEAR": "10", "3 MONTHS": "877", "6 MONTHS": "1145" } }],
    values = ["10", "20", "30", "40"],
    order = Object.fromEntries(values.map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]));

data.sort(({ rs: a }, { rs: b }) => order[getValue(a)] - order[getValue(b)]);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```